# Difference between possessive pronoun and possessive case of pronoun

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns

What is the difference between possessive pronoun and possessive case of pronoun?

Pronoun              possessive case

> I                          mine

> That                          ?

> Everyone                  ?

What is the possessive case for that, which, everyone, everbody etc?

Above mentioned **mine** is possessive pronoun or possessive case?

Comment: Please look up possessive pronouns (mine, yours, his/hers/its, ours, yours, theirs) That and everyone are not possessive pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

Possessive pronouns are words that show possessions referring to the subjects retrievable from the context. For example, "this book is mine." "Mine" is the possessive pronoun of the speaker "I". As for everyone,  or everybody, the possessive pronoun would be "theirs" because from the speaker's point of view, everyone or everybody is a third plural subject.

Comment: "Everyone" and "everybody" as subjects are singular. We can say "Everyone/everybody **is** here", but "Everyone/everybody **are** here" is ungrammatical.

Comment: OP is asking (partly) about the possibility of _that_'s as in 'Look at these two cars. This car's windows are broken; that's are not."

Answer (score 0):

English doesn't have "case".   There are remnants of the cases used in Anglo-Saxon, but there is no comprehensive case system in modern English.

So "mine" is a possessive pronoun.

English doesn't have cases, so there is no genitive case of "that". And while you can form the possessive "Everyone's" with the clitic *'s*  there is no genitive form. You can use "of" to form possessive expressions with "that", but this is very rare in practice (and so learners should normally avoid it)

<sub>The Old English neuter genitive of *Þæt* was *Þæs* but that is absolutely irrelevant to modern English</sub>